# Can't pre-populate textarea with jQuery based on a data from a table

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Somehow I can't pre-populate textarea with a data from a table based on a code below:

HTML:

```
<td id="1_desc" class="edit_desc"><div class="gallery clearfix"><a href="{url}" rel="wp-prettyPhoto" title="VIDEO TITLE HERE">View Commercial</a></div></td>
<textarea id="edit_form_desc" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
var desc = jQuery("#1_desc").html();
jQuery("#edit_form_desc").val(desc);
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/RkmYJ/

When I have "hardcoded" variable 'desc' everything works fine.

Any clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the browser is tossing the parent-less `<td>` you've described above. Wrap it up in a table, and things seem to work much better:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="1_desc" class="edit_desc"><div class="gallery clearfix"><a href="{url}" rel="wp-prettyPhoto" title="VIDEO TITLE HERE">View Commercial</a></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<textarea id="edit_form_desc" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea>​
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rjzaworski/7H5UL/)

Answer (score 0):

If you make it an actual `<table></table>` and not just a `<td>`, an element that has no meaning outside of a `<table></table>` then it works: [jsfiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/RkmYJ/1/)

```
 <table><tr><td id="1_desc" class="edit_desc"><div class="gallery clearfix"><a href="{url}" rel="wp-prettyPhoto" title="VIDEO TITLE HERE">View Commercial</a></div></td></tr></table>

<textarea id="edit_form_desc" rows="7" cols="50"></textarea>
```